# Ubuntu sed - appends in URL instead of replacing

Tags: bash, sed, ubuntu-16.04

I have a URL in a .yml file which has can be of types as given below:

```
https://blog.com/public/
```

or

```
https://blog.com/public/1534248704/static
```

The number in URL above is unknown to me.

I have to replace these url patterns in file with a new random number generated, so it looks something like:

```
https://blog.com/public/151234567/static
```

The command I am using is:

```
sed -i 's, https://blog.com/public/, https://blog.com/public/151234567/static,g' config.yml
```

It works well if I only have a URL without a number (first URL), but if the URL has a number, instead of getting the replaced URL, I get something in which the new number is appended to the old number in the URL as below:

```
https://blog.com/public/1534248704/static151234567/static
```

Please let me know how to replace this completely or the thing I am doing wrong here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've modified sample to show the problem and solution in a simpler way, changing it to suit real usecase is left to the user

```
$ # here only 'cat' will be replaced
$ echo 'cat cater' | sed 's/cat/dog/g'
dog doger

$ # here both 'cat' and 'cater' will be replaced
$ # -E option to enable ERE, some sed versions would need -r instead of -E
$ echo 'cat cater' | sed -E 's/cat|cater/dog/g'
dog dog
$ # using group and quantifier to simplify regex
$ echo 'cat cater' | sed -E 's/cat(er)?/dog/g'
dog dog

$ # possible cases to take care of
$ echo 'concat catered' | sed -E 's/cat(er)?/dog/g'
condog doged
```

Another issue with `/cat|cater/` is that it depends on regex engine implementation. On `GNU sed`, order doesn't matter, longest match will win, not sure about other implementations... here's an example with `perl`

```
$ echo 'cat cater' | perl -pe 's/cat|cater/dog/g'
dog doger
$ echo 'cat cater' | perl -pe 's/cater|cat/dog/g'
dog dog
$ echo 'cat cater' | perl -pe 's/cat(er)?/dog/g'
dog dog
```

so, `/cat(er)?/` seems better suited when there are multiple replacements in single line

Comment: This doesn't solves my issue, the command I used is

`echo 'https://blog.com/public/1534248704/static' | sed -E 's, https://blog.com/public/([0-9]/static)?, https://blog.com/public/151234567/static, g'`

Comment: you would need `[0-9]+` instead of `[0-9]`.. also, for this sample with echo, you would need to remove the space after `s,`

Comment: Thanks a lot ! and with the -i flag it even replaces the URL in file.